# React - State Update value only of Particular key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm trying to experiment with React, I have a issue of updating state values of a particular key.

Here is my state

```
this.state = {
        connections : {
            facebook : "http://facebook.com",
            flickr : null,
            foursquare : null,
            googleplus : null,
            id : 0,
            instagram : "http://instagram.com/",
            openstreetmap : null,
            pinterest : null,
            place_id : 1,
            tomtom : null,
            tripadvisor : null,
            twitter : "http://twitter.com",
            vimeo : null,
            wikipedia : null,
            yelp : null,
            youtube : null
        },
        contact : {

        }
    }
```

I'm calling a external component and sending parameters to it.

```
<Connection type="Facebook" icon={facebookIcon} placeholder="Add Facebook Link" name="facebook" value={this.state.connections.facebook} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
<Connection type="Twitter" icon={twitterIcon} placeholder="Add Twitter Link" name="twitter" value={this.state.connections.twitter} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
<Connection type="Instagram" icon={instagramIcon} placeholder="Add Instagram Link" name="instagram" value={this.state.connections.instagram} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
```

Component in external file:

```
<input type="text" name={this.props.name} placeholder={this.state.placeholder} value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
```

On change of value in textbox,

```
handleChange(e) {        
    this.setState({
        connections : {[e.target.name]: e.target.value}
    })
}
```

While I try to change any field values, it sets the rest 2 with empty. For example, if I try to edit textbox of Facebook, it sets Twitter and Instagram values to empty.

May I know what I'm doing wrong in setting handleChange? I'm sure its something wrong with **this.setState**, but not sure how to target particular key value.

Comment: first of all, you should not be having such a long list of local state. Reason a) Hard to manage 2) it will break you code if you try to change anything.                                        Break  the  large component into smaller component. for your problem  try to add e.preventDefault inside handleChange function

Comment: @KhalidAzam Thanks for letting me know about it, I don't see any way to break the list, do you have any tips on this? Coz, my next component is amenities, and it has a list which is 100 times in size of this one. I was wondering to store in as external js and import here. Any better ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case you need get previous state and create new *(for merge states you can use `Object.assign`, spread operator `...`, or lodash `merge`)*, because [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate),

> Performs a shallow merge of nextState into current state.

```
this.setState({    
  connections: Object.assign(
    {}, 
    this.state.connections,
    { [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
  ),
  contact: {}
});
```

Example

```js
class Connection extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <input 
      type="text"
      placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
      name={this.props.name}
      value={this.props.value} 
      onChange={this.props.onChange} />
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      connections : {
        facebook : "http://facebook.com",
        flickr : null,
        foursquare : null,
        googleplus : null,
        id : 0,
        instagram : "http://instagram.com/",
        openstreetmap : null,
        pinterest : null,
        place_id : 1,
        tomtom : null,
        tripadvisor : null,
        twitter : "http://twitter.com",
        vimeo : null,
        wikipedia : null,
        yelp : null,
        youtube : null
      },
      contact: {}
    }
  }
  
  handleChange(e) {        
    
    
    this.setState({    
      connections: Object.assign(
        {}, 
        this.state.connections,
        { [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
      ),
      contact: {}
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      
        <Connection 
          type="Facebook" 
          placeholder="Add Facebook Link"
          name="facebook" 
          value={this.state.connections.facebook}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
        />
    
        <Connection 
          type="Twitter" 
          placeholder="Add Twitter Link" 
          name="twitter" 
          value={this.state.connections.twitter} 
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />

        <Connection 
          type="Instagram"
          placeholder="Add Instagram Link"
          name="instagram" 
          value={this.state.connections.instagram}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

`setState` performs a shallow merge instead of a deep one (more explanation in [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)), so you're completely overwriting all of `connections` with just your one value. If you want to keep the other keys in `connections` intact, you can change `handleChange` to this:

```
handleChange(e) {        
    this.setState({
        connections : {...this.state.connections, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}
    })
}
```

This will shallow copy all of `this.state.connections`, and then set `e.target.name` over top of it.

Comment: Got it Drew. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the problem is with your setState.

```
handleChange(e) {        
    this.setState({
        connections : {[e.target.name]: e.target.value} //this will trigger twitter and instagram with empty value.
    })
}
```

An simple workaround would be:

```
handleChange(e) {        
    this.setState({
        connections : {[e.target.name]: e.target.value, twitter: 'initial val', instagram: 'initial val'}
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should actually rather use

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState(oldState => ({
    connections: {[e.target.name]: e.target.value, ...oldState.connections},
  }));
}
```

because otherwise you might overwrite state-changes that have not been applied yet.

see https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: right answer for this question